# Strange behaviour in PHP strtotime

Tags: php

```
$one   = '2016-10-11';
$two   = '2016-10-13';
$three = '2016-10-15';
$four  = '2016-10-16';
$five  = '2016-10-17';

$output_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

var_dump(
    strtotime($one),
    strtotime($two),
    strtotime($three),
    strtotime($four),
    strtotime($five),
    date($output_format, strtotime($one)),
    date($output_format, strtotime($two)),
    date($output_format, strtotime($three)),
    date($output_format, strtotime($four)),
    date($output_format, strtotime($five))
);
```

This outputs

```
int 1476154800

int 1476327600

int 1476500400

int 1476586800

int 1476669600

string '2016-10-11 00:00:00' (length=19)

string '2016-10-13 00:00:00' (length=19)

string '2016-10-15 00:00:00' (length=19)

string '2016-10-16 01:00:00' (length=19)

string '2016-10-17 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

Why '2016-10-16 01:00:00' has 01:00:00 and the others have 00:00:00?
I'm using PHP 5.5.29.

Comment: I ran it and got expected output: `int(1476158400) int(1476331200) int(1476504000) int(1476590400) int(1476676800) string(19) "2016-10-11 00:00:00" string(19) "2016-10-13 00:00:00" string(19) "2016-10-15 00:00:00" string(19) "2016-10-16 00:00:00" string(19) "2016-10-17 00:00:00"`

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.18

Comment: Running it online using http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3dbbac7c8bf43ee4e8d05f0132feaf0d7629464 I got only `00:00:00` for each dates.

Comment: tis odd indeed, almost acts as if the DST settings forgot when DST actually starts

Comment: What's your timezone? And what's the output of `var_dump(ini_get("date.timezone"));`

Comment: DST in Brazil and other places is October 16, 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be related to "Daylight saving time" (DST). My php.ini timezone is currently set to

```
date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo
```

Here in Brazil we entered the "Daylight saving time" (DST) at 2016-10-16, so that's why it has 01:00:00. 
Interesting, that's the first time it occurred to me in years.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that author of the question is living in Brazil, where DST actually happened on 16 October 2016 - https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia?year=2016